# Accessing /Creating objects of one class in multiple files in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a couple of classes lets say,

```
public class A
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Fixes { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
}
```

I am using these two classes in two files (Webforms) like below.

```
var allVars= (from p in doc.Elements("Patches").Elements("Patch").Elements("Fix")
                      select new B
                      {
                          Fixes = p.Value,
                          Date = (p.Parent.Attribute("date") == null) ? "NA" : p.Parent.Attribute("date").Value,
                          Link = (p.Attribute("Ticket") == null) ? "" : p.Attribute("Ticket").Value,
                          Document = (p.Attribute("Document") != null) ? p.Attribute("Document").Value : ""
                      }
                          );

 var allVariables= (from f in doc.Elements("Features").Elements("Feature")
                       select new A
                       {
                           Date=(f.Parent.Attribute("date") == null) ? "NA" : f.Parent.Attribute("date").Value,
                           Name = f.Attribute("name").Value,
                           Description = f.Value,
                           Link = f.Attribute("Ticket").Value,
                           Document = (f.Attribute("Document") != null) ? f.Attribute("Document").Value : null
                       });
```

So, the clases are used like this in multiple webforms(Partial classes) in my application. Instead of defining them separately in each class. I would like them to define once and use them in anyfile just like that. I am sure that C# would have some mechanism like this but I couldn't recollect the feature name and how to reuse it.

Could someone let me know how this is possible.

Comment: Write a method and call the method from your forms?

Comment: Are you saying that I need to write a method to do the one in my second block and define that method in a common file that contains the class definitions and call it from my forms? Can't we use namespaces here? define the classes in a .cs file in a namespace, use that namespace in webforms with "using" directive?

Answer (score 0):

Define it as static function inside those two classes:

```html
public class A
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
public static dynamic Get A()
{

var allVariables= (from f in doc.Elements("Features").Elements("Feature")
                       select new A
                       {
                           Date=(f.Parent.Attribute("date") == null) ? "NA" : f.Parent.Attribute("date").Value,
                           Name = f.Attribute("name").Value,
                           Description = f.Value,
                           Link = f.Attribute("Ticket").Value,
                           Document = (f.Attribute("Document") != null) ? f.Attribute("Document").Value : null
                       });
return allVariables;

}
}


public class B
{
    public string Fixes { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }ynamig
    public string Document { get; set; }
public static dynamic getB()
{
var allVars= (from p in doc.Elements("Patches").Elements("Patch").Elements("Fix")
                      select new B
                      {
                          Fixes = p.Value,
                          Date = (p.Parent.Attribute("date") == null) ? "NA" : p.Parent.Attribute("date").Value,
                          Link = (p.Attribute("Ticket") == null) ? "" : p.Attribute("Ticket").Value,
                          Document = (p.Attribute("Document") != null) ? p.Attribute("Document").Value : ""
                      }
                          );

return allVars;
}

}
```

and then you can call these functions from your pages as:

A.getA()

B.getB()

Comment: The definition of these classes should be in a .cs file with name say "xyz.cs". Then how our webform file know to use the classes from those file? I am talking something like #include in C++

Comment: Just add xyz.cs to the project. If you need to use/reference it in more than one project, compile xyz.cs as a separate project (class library) and add reference to this new assembly to any project that has to use it.

Comment: Create New Class Inside your project and add that code to it
Make sure that they have the same namespace as your project